# How to pass function as prop for a client component in Next.js 13.2?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

Let's say I have a table component, that gets an array of objects to show. Now in the first column, I have a button for every row. I want to return the data of the row (object) to the page, that corresponds to the button pressed. How do I do that by keeping the page a server and the table a client component? I can't pass a `(row: Object) => any` to the table from the page.

I tried using Context for the whole layout, but that doesn't seem practical at all.

Comment: are you using the new app directory ?

Comment: Yes. I know, it's only experimental, but this should work some way.

Comment: Yes, but I ask for a reason. If we don't know your config or your code we can't guess